# How to fix the access restriction warning from VS Code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I want to remove these warnings/ error in VS Code
`Access restriction: The type 'Application' is not API (restriction on required library'/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_11.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar')`

If I open the same folder in a IDE I do not get any warnings like this. I am using the Java Extension Pack. I love everything about it except the fact it highlights my whole code with these warnings which is annoying. I read this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25222811/access-restriction-the-type-application-is-not-api-restriction-on-required-l)
It has answers specific on the project structure of a IDE. There is no option for changing the project structure in VS Code. If there is a option please let me know. As this is a software specific question I thought Super User was the place to ask. Please help me fix these warnings or if there is a way to disable the highlighted warnings in VS Code.

Thanks.

Comment: Its been more than a month, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Insert classentry with the pattern of your package name in .classpath file and set accessrule as 'accessbile'.

Like this:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8/">
    <accessrules>
        <accessrule kind="accessible" pattern="**/javafx/**"/>
    </accessrules>
</classpathentry>
```